# Finding the critical point of a function $f(x,y)$ with restrictions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have the following problem. Find the *critical* points for:

$$f(x,y) = xy + 2x -ln(x^2y),$$

in the first quadrant $x>0$ and $y>0$, and show that $f(x,y)$ has a *minimum* in the first quadrant.

I found $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}$ and they are $y+2 +\frac{-2}{x}$ and $x - \frac {1}{y}$, respectively. However, I do not know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find points $(x,y)$ such that

(1)  $y+2 -\frac{2}{x}=0$

and

(2)  $x - \frac {1}{y}=0$

From (2) we get $y= \frac {1}{x}$. Now proceed with (1).

Comment: Okay, I got that $x= \frac {1}{2}$ and $y= 2$. Does that mean I'm done ?

Comment: I know $( \frac {1}{2},2) $ lie in the first quadrant but how do I show that this critical point is a minimum ?

Comment: Tipp: Hessian matrix

Comment: okay I'll look into it.